# A qualifying-exam problem related to Clifford theorem in representation theory

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

[image]

> I am not sure : does this problem can be solve directly by Maschke's
>   theorem, which states that every representation of a finite group is
>   completely reducible.  Perhaps I made some stupid mistake.
>
> What's more, can somebody told me how Clifford's theorem can work
>   here? I am not familiar with Clifford theorem.
>
> Please help!

Comment: is not there is a restriction on the characteristic of the field concerning the order of the group G?

Comment: Do you mean G is not assumed to be finite?

Comment: Clifford's Theorem does not have any hypotheses concerning $|G|$ and the characteristic of the field. But Maschke's Theorem assumes that $|G|$ is not divisible by the field characteristic, so you cannot use Machke's Theorem here.